# discord.py await command giving unexpected error

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot for the first time and am trying to make it so it either sets your nickname or adds it to a list. I'm getting a syntax error. Where am I going wrong?

Ive tried modifying my code in all the ways I can think of(to no avail).

I expected for this to ask and add a nickname, then write out the first nickname in the list, which it isn't.

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author != client.user:
    if '!ClearNick' in message.content:
      await client.change_nickname(message.author, message.author.name)
    elif '!SetNick' in message.content:
      if message.author.id in users:
        await client.change_nickname(message.author, 'lol')
      elif message.author.id not in users:
        users.append(message.author.id)
        nicknames.append(raw_input('What nickname: ')
        await client.change_nickname(message.author, nicknames)
```

It returns:

```
await client.change_nick...
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please don't link to your code; post the code itself (not a picture of it!) in your question. Without that, your question is less helpful to other people in the future if the link expires.

Comment: @larsks fixed, thanks!

Comment: We need all the code. This is not enough to give us the context we need. Where is client defined? We can't even run this and get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've forgotten a `)` at this line `nicknames.append(raw_input('What nickname: ')`

In addition I'd like to make some suggestions. You can set a command prefix, that means you don't have to check for `!ClearNick` but can define a new command via

`def ClearNick(ctx, args)`

and

`def SetNick(ctx,args)`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Do I mark this solved somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure all awaited code is inside an `async def` function statement. It will not work otherwise (giving a SyntaxError).

Comment: ~Im using Repl.it, which was working just fine until I added the last "await" line, if I delete it, then it works just fine.
Note: It is running Python 3.6.1~

This is the code in terms of where the ```def``` is: https://paste.pics/e0b02eba8cd8feb979f196cdfdd41239

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Just realised that your picture had a version number in it.

Comment: See Vulpex's answer, it should fix it. Also your last change_nickname statement won't work. It does also need to be in the on_ready async function.

Comment: Noted. I need to delete it anyways since a ```raw_input``` won't work.